# ScrollViewer is not working inside groupbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar, groupbox

I want to include `ScrollViewer` in my `Groupbox`, but it is not working. My code is:

```
<GroupBox 
           Margin="10,10,0,0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Height="150"           
            >
                    <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               
                <Label 
                    Margin="0,6,0,0"
                    Content="SSID"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    >      
                </Label>
                
                <TextBox
                      Margin="0,6,0,6"
                    Grid.Column="1">
                    
                </TextBox>

                <Label 
                     Margin="0,6,0,0"
                    Content="(1024)"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    >
                </Label>
                <Label 
                     Margin="0,6,0,0"
                    Content="Authentication Mode"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    >
                </Label>
                <ComboBox 
                        Margin="0,6,0,6" 
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ACAvailableSecurityTypes}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ACSelectedSecurityType}"
                />
                <Label
                    
                      Margin="0,6,0,0"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Content="VLAN"
                      />
                
                <TextBox
                      Margin="0,6,0,6"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    />
            
                <Label Grid.Row="2"
                       Grid.Column="2"
                    Content="(1-4094)"/>
                
                <Button
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Content="Add SSID"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Width="70"
                    Style="{StaticResource AppButtons}"/>
            </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </GroupBox>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? It looks as if whole `Grid` fits nicely in the 150 height that you assign to `GroupBox`. There's nothing hidden below

Comment: Scrollbar is displaying but it's not movable !

Comment: Because `Grid` fits inside space given to `GroupBox` so there's nothing to scroll

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Order to See your Scroll bar, your **scrollviewer** should have lesser height than your groupbox, do like this, you can see the scrollbar, Set the **height** and **VerticalScrollBarVisibility**

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="100" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <GroupBox 
           Margin="10,10,0,0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            Height="150"           
            >
           ......

        </GroupBox>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 4):

Place the `ScrollViewer` outside the `GroupBox`, not inside:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <GroupBox Margin="10,10,0,0"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
              Height="150" >

        ...
        ...

    </GroupBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Placing the `GroupBox` inside the `ScrollViewer` cause `GroupBox` header to disappear when scrolling.

I solved the problem, keeping the `ScollViewer` inside the `GroupBox` by setting the `Height` of the `ScrollViewer` to match `GroupBox` `Height`:

```
<GroupBox Header="Testing 123">
    <ScrollViewer Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=GroupBox}, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Image .../>
    </ScrollViewer>
</GroupBox>
```